# External/ internal storage viewing file

Tags: android, file, file-io

I have my app writing a file to the 'Download' folder (just some text, the content is irrelevant). Using a file manager app I am able to see the text file and view it. I then plug in the Nexus 7 tablet to the PC and navigate to the tablet in Windows Explorer. The 'Download' folder is empty, I put in an image file into the 'Download' folder just to have a file in there. I go back to the file manager app on the tablet and now I can see both the image file and my text file wrote from the app.

As far as Windows Explorer is concerned there is only 1 file in the 'Download' folder, the file manager app says there are 2 files. If I create a file of the same name on Windows and put it into the 'Download' folder it will overwrite the text file created from the app. If I re-create the text file from the app it will over-write the file I created on Windows.

Can anyone tell me why this happens? And why I can't just 'see' the file? I have `-rw` permissions on the file...

(I have also done the whole 'show hidden file' things in the folder preferences).

Comment: Hey! Yes, I've tried the link you suggested above but it's not doing it for me :(